# Does application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: get called if Background App Refresh is disabled in settings?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

I'm using `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` to fetch some data from an API whenever iOS invokes this callback.

From my understanding of background app refresh, I'd never need to check the value for `[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus]` but I just want to confirm - If background app refresh is disabled in my device's settings, will iOS ever call `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not call it.
But you will still be able to force it from Xcode from Debug->Simulate background fetch